# AppenginePlugin unsupported major.minor version 51 error importing gradle project in IntelliJ on a mac

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea, gradle

Failing to import project. Gives Unsupported Major.Minor version 51 error when importing from build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

(copied from [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27059344/appengineplugin-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-appengine-1-9-17))

### Solution:

Solution for me was to edit `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/Info.plist`

Find these two lines towards the bottom:

```
<key>JVMVersion</key>
<string>1.6*</string>
```

Change it to `1.7*`, so that it looks like so:

```
<key>JVMVersion</key>
<string>1.7*</string>
```

Then restart your IDE.